# How do I drop certain rows of my table in python?

Tags: python

I have a table with data for multiple continents. Now I want to delete every row where the continent isn't Europe or Africa.
With:

```
df1 = df1.loc[(df1["region"] == "Europe")]
```

I get every row with "Europe" but I miss the "Africa" ones.
Is there a way to include an "or"-operator? It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
df1 = df1.loc[(df1["region"].isin(["Europe", "Africa"]))]
```

Comment: Apparently this is an invalid syntax. Python doesn't like the ".in".

Comment: ive made an edit it should be .isin()

Answer (score 3):

The question says drop, which needs to be adapted as follows if you want to drop the rows containing the mentioned value.

```
df1[(df1.region == "Europe") & (df1.region == "Africa")]
```

or you can also use the `query` command to achieve the same at the faster rate

```
df1.query("region == ['Europe', 'Africa']")
```

Comment: Are you sure that `query` is faster? It is indeed shorter to type, but I am not sure for execution speed...

Answer (score 3):

Also option `df1[df1["region"].isin(["Europe", "Africa"])]`